# Set size/dimensions of ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, arraylist

### The problem

I have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s. I am copying one over to the other, except in a different order (a rotation of the elements by 180°, but that's not important).

I have this generic code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
        list.get(r).set(c, "an element from the other list");
    }
}
```

I'm arbitrarily using sizes `4` for the number of rows and `5` for the number of columns.

However, this throws an index out of bounds error, obviously because I have no dimensions for the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

I know that when creating an `ArrayList`, [you can give it an initial capacity for a constructor parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29). However, I don't know how to apply that to this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

This won't compile, but this is essentially what I want:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>(5)>(4);
```

---

### My mediocre solution

To give the matrix some dimensions before I attempted to copy the list over, I just iterated for the number of rows I wanted and added a list of size of the number of columns I wanted to each row.

I used a regular array and converted it to an `ArrayList` just so that the elements would have a default value of null, and so would contribute to the size.

```
for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
    // list.add( new ArrayList<String>(5) ); // doesn't work
    list.add( new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList(new String[5]) ) );
}
```

So that works for setting the size, because enough elements will be added to the matrix, but it's not the preferred solution.

---

### The question

Is there any way to set the initial dimensions of an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s during the initialization? Or just something different that iterating and adding `null` values?

Comment: An `ArrayList` is not an array. It can grow dynamically.

Comment: _"I know that when creating an ArrayList, you can give it a size for a constructor parameter."_ You don't give a size, you just specify the initial capacity of the list. The size remains 0 as you didn't add any elments.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Right, but I need to give it an initial size.

Comment: @ZouZou Capacity means the max size it can have. Is that actually what I would be doing? Not actually editing the size, but just stating the max possible size?

Comment: @mikeyaworski No, it constructs an array with the specified capacity (10 by default if you don't specify one). But if you add more elements the backed array will be resized automatically. For example `List<String> s = new ArrayList<>(5); for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) s.add("a");` will add 10 strings to the List.

Comment: When you construct the contained ArrayList, set its capacity...or initialize it with x objects

Comment: You could also extend ArrayList or implement List

Comment: @crush That's what I don't know how to do. If you do, please write up an answer.

Comment: You **could** create an own implementation like a `FixedSizeList`, but I can hardly imagine a sensible use case for this. It would remove quite some flexibility. BTW: You should anyhow declare your structure as `List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`. And in order to initialize an ArrayList with a certain size, you can use `list = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.nCopies(size, (String)null)`.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(4);
for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
    ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    ls.add("" + (r + 1));
    list.add(ls);
}
for (ArrayList<String> ls : list) {
    System.out.println(ls);
}
```

Note: do not confuse [`ArrayList#size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--), current number of elements in the collection, with `ArrayList#capacity`, current maximum size of the collection (which cannot be accessed).

For more info, refer to: [`ArrayList(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-):

> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

Note that using `List<List<Whatever>>` you're not creating a 2D dynamic array, you're creating a dynamic list which will contains dynamic lists, thus you **must** initialize every list by separate and add lists (from any size) into another list, and every list would have a dynamic size (despite the values they have). There's no 2d dynamic array nor dynamic array of arrays in plain Java, unless you create such class or import it from a third party library.

---

Looks like this structure would suit better for your case:

```
String[][] stringArrayOfArray = new String[4][5];
```

---

Another very odd way (not recommended) to accomplish what you want/need would be:

```
List<String>[] arrayOfList = new List[4];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.length; i++) {
    arrayOfList[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: So you just created an ArrayList with an initial capacity of 4 ArrayLists. But then, just like what I did, you had to add a list for the columns each iteration. I am hoping for a way to set the capacity initially of each ArrayList in the outer ArrayList.

Comment: @mikeyaworski note the edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: The regular array is more simple for constructing, but ultimately I didn't want to use it. This was actually for a computing contest and the ArrayList came in handy later for removing elements and such. Just the initialization was something I was curious to make easier.

Comment: @mikeyaworski just to note: there's no 2d dynamic array in plain Java, unless you create such class or import it from a third party library.